# make a batch file that adds itself to startup and (windows 10)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

so I was wondering is there a way to make a batch file that adds itself to startup
without getting the error: access is denied. 0 file moved
here is my bat code:

```
move "C:\Users\Deathblade\Desktop\Startup bat\funtime.bat" "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
move "C:\Users\Deathblade\Desktop\Startup bat\funtime.bat" "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

pause
```

That's the end of it so yeah all help appreciated, even .vbs script or anything
accepted

Comment: Right-click -> Run as Administrator

Comment: Are you looking for something that will self-elevate?

Comment: how can I make it so when double clicked it runs as admin?

Comment: ye so you don't have to right click run as admin but it runs as admin already

Comment: Please learn how to post code before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what I did was create a shortcut and went into the properties and changed it to automatic admin when run, to get rid of the shortcut and move the .bat file I made it so when the .bat file was run it deleted the shortcut and moved the .bat so it was never seen again.